Is there any major mistake in this PCB?
Here are the schematics and layout of a PCB I designed and had made. This is mainly an ESP32 module with I2C(5V+3V3)/1Wire/digital I/O connectors for external devices/boards. It also provides a high quality 5V power source using a LT6658 for yet another external board.
The relay commands I/O are destined to another board that contains all the needed stuff to operate relays (transistor, fly-back diode) (this other card works well when receiving the I/O from an ESP8266 devkit board).
DFR1 is a 5V/600mA regulator module (https://www.gotronic.fr/art-regulateur-5-vcc-dfr0569-29560.htm).



After about 10 minutes of flawless work, the GROUND wire between this PCB's TX/RX connector and an external USB/FTDI board just started to seriously smoke, and the 3V3 LED turned OFF  slowly in a few seconds.
I obviously powered the board off, and tried to analyse the issue. It turns out that, no surprise there, the GND and 3V3 tracks were connected, and (more surprisingly, at least for me) the connection comes from the ESP32 module itself (its GND and 3V3 inputs were connected).
I guess this is just the consequence of an overcurrent that might have melted something within the ESP32 module, but I could not find the root cause. This might be because of a bad soldering process on my end, but I am not sure, and found no clear evidence of that.
So I'm wondering if I have missed something obvious in the board design. Is there something wrong with the schematics or the PCB layout that might have caused this?

There appear to be at least two air wires (missing connections) shown in your screenshot - the two thin lines between parts of the same trace. The GND pins of U2 are not connected to the rest of the GND on the board as a result

The 3.3V net is also split in half connected only via the lead frame of U1.

What component is "DFR1" and why is the second output of LT6658 left flotating? It might turn itself into an oscillator or output more voltage than it can handle.

@Justme (1) DFR1 is this module : https://www.gotronic.fr/art-regulateur-5-vcc-dfr0569-29560.htm (2) I did not know both LT6658 outputs had to be connected. Since the first one delivers enough current for my needs, I only used this one. Should I connect them together?

@TomCarpenter (1) The missing GND connection for U2 is a mistake on my part, I did not send the right PCB schematic. I will update the image. (2) Regarding the 3.3V tracks, I thought U1 lead frame connection was enough. Why is the connection between the two 3.3V nets required?

@Silverspur Please add that info to the question, it does not belong in the comments. Also no you should not connect the two outputs together. You should just connect the output like it should be connected, even if you don't use it.

Non of your I/Os seem to have any kind of protection. I would at least add some resistors. Is "RELAY_CMD" used to control a relay? If it is, does it have a fly-back diode?

@nanash1 The relay commands I/O are destined to another board with all the needed stuff (transistor, fly-back diode) (this other card works well when receiving I/O from an ESP8266 devkit board). What kind of protection pattern do you think of with a resistor for other I/O (1Wire, I2C) ?

Iirc these old bad linear regulators were picky with the output caps having a specific ESR - not too high, not too low. I don't know what caps you've picked but check with your scope that the AMS1117 is behaving as a regulator and not as an oscillator, as these parts tend to do.

Your ground plane is compromised by the long traces. Can you try to split them into sections and run as much as possible on top layer instead?
